# code works on localhost but not live server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, server, localhost

My code works perfectly fine on localhost. However, when I copied and pasted the exact same code on my live server I got this error message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). I checked my folder path and it looks correct to me. I don't know what is wrong here.

```
var folder = "image/";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: folder,
        success: function (data) {
         console.log("successful load")
            $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
                      theImageList.push(folder + val );
            };
        })
            left_show_image(theImageList[shuffledComparison[0][0]],window.innerWidth/10*4.88, screen.width/3, "left")
            right_show_image(theImageList[shuffledComparison[0][1]],window.innerWidth/10*4.88, screen.width/3, "right")\
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("cannot read your folder")
        }
    })
})
```

This is really confusing to me and I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Could you provide a document structure for your project? Is there a directory `images` that is relative to this file?

Comment: can you provide a link to your live server?.. the issue could indeed be related to relative paths as stated in the answers below

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the folder path. 
Try adding the slash before image:

```
var folder = "/image/";
```

OR

```
var folder = "~/image/";
```

Also place this inside of the document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var folder = "/image/";
    $.ajax({
        url: folder,
        success: function (data) {
        console.log("successful load")
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if (val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
                  theImageList.push(folder + val );
        };
    })
        left_show_image(theImageList[shuffledComparison[0]
[0]],window.innerWidth/10*4.88, screen.width/3, "left")
        right_show_image(theImageList[shuffledComparison[0]
[1]],window.innerWidth/10*4.88, screen.width/3, "right")\
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("cannot read your folder")
    }
}) 
})
```

This will use the base url and then search for the image folder so it should work for both local host and on the server. Also, make sure you have uploaded your image folder to the server

Comment: Try adding the var folder = "~/image/"; inside of the document.ready funciton

Comment: It's super strange because when I specified image src such as image/mypic1.png it worked so I don't think my access to my image folder was denied. However, when I tried to get the list of all files in my image folder through 'image/' or '/image/','~/image/' like you suggested, I got GET 404().

Comment: The 404 means it can not find the path specified. Try replacing using the absolute path to the folder. var folder = "http://{url}/image/"

Comment: You also need to have directory browsing enabled at the server level.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/directorybrowse

Answer (score 0):

Using relative paths in javascipt may cause 404 error when deploying web site under a virtual or root directory.

image folder should work with both virtual or root directory.
you provide a variable for application path such as appUrl.

var  appUrl  = 'localhost or live server root folder'

var folder = appUrl + "/image";